# Run-time Error '1004' that errors on an Autoshape Command

Tags: excel, vba

I have a template that creates a new tab when a button is pushed on the main menu.  On that new tab it brings over some data from the main menu and creates two buttons (autoshapes) that also gets assigned text and a macro for each because the actions are different for each button.  However when it gets to the autoshape command it returns a Run-time Error '1004'.  I have prior versions of the spreadsheet that do not have all the bells and whistles of the new spreadsheet, but if I run the functionality from the prior version it works fine.  If I copy and paste the VB specific to this functionality it still runs into the Run-time Error.  It has no problem making the autoshape using exactly the same code in the prior version..... I'm at a loss.

The exact code that causes the error is:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, 603.75, 7.5, 156.75, 49.5).Select
```

I've copied the code that works in prior versions to the current version and it still runs into the same error.

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, 603.75, 7.5, 156.75, 49.5).Select
```

I want a Rounded Rectangular shape created so I can assign text and a macro to it for some additional functionality after user data input.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I posted this about 10 minutes too soon.  I found on another question that I needed to be sure the Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library is checked in the VBA menu under Tools\ References.  I did so and it fixed the issue.